# Session - timeout - idle handling Multi-treads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, session, timeout

I am trying to get my head around session - timeout - idle handling Multi-treads in Java.

I have a server & client application comunicating via telnet where I need to check if the user has been typing (anything), clicking (anywhere), or moved the mouse  within a periode of time.

If not, the user will be prompted with a dialog box, asking if he wants to conntinue session or not. ...(and If not, the user will automatically be logged out within the next minute or so.)

My application has multiple threads. ( - One user per thread). So I am not sure how to approatch this the best (**and easiest**) way?

I know it is a wide and far-fetched question, but I was hoping some of you could give me a pointer or tip in the right direction... :)

I was kind of hoping for a simple method that could check:
(a bit pseudo code on the fly:)

```
if (idle = true){
timer.start();
if (timer > 120sec)
displayWaringJFrame("Continue Session?  - YES or NO ?)
displayTimer.start();
if (displayTimer > 30sec)
application.user.closeSession()
```

...or something like that! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is a class java.lang.Thread.

You can create class and implements interface Runnable

```
public class Session implements Runnable{
    public void run(){
        //your code
    }
}
```

in main function create class Thread and as constuctor argument set instance of Session class after this importatnt is call method .start()

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    new Thread(new Session()).start();
}
```

Much more convenient way to work with threads is java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService and java.util.concurrent.Executors

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

1. if you want a persistent timer you can use a library like [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) which then you can run a job class you write after a period of time. You can cancel scheduled job, re-schedule etc...

2. You don't necessarily need a thread per user for this to work. A timer object usually has internal threads to handle the workload, either with Quartz or the memory only Java timers.